# Query on Execution environment of JavaScript & Python

Tags: javascript, python

Below diagram is retrieved after running JavaScript code(top-half) on [link1](http://jstutor.herokuapp.com/) and python code(bottom-half) on [link2](http://pythontutor.com/)

[image]

My question:

I see that names `foo` & `bar` are already sitting in global frame(in blue) of JavaScript Execution environment(EE) unlike python's EE? How did JavaScript interpreter know about these two names before starting interpretation?

Comment: This is too broad a question; you have *three* different questions in one.

Comment: Shall i remove second question?

Comment: OK i removed last two questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How did JavaScript interpreter know about these two names before starting interpretation?

That's something called [**hoisting**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20hoisting). Before the engine executes any line of code (of a function), it looks for all variable and function declarations and creates a binding in the current environment ([§10.5, steps 5 and 8](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5)). In case of variable declarations, the value is `undefined` because the assignment has not taken place yet.

Apparently *Python* doesn't work that way, but I'm not familiar enough with its inner workings to give an authoritative  answer about that.

Comment: Felix As you say it creates a binding, but i see that the values are 'undefined' as per the diagram

Comment: That's the default value. The value you specified in the code is still only assigned when that particular line is executed.

Comment: @Sham a freshly-declared symbol is `undefined` because no assignment to it has yet been executed. Declarations are hoisted; initialization expressions are not.

Comment: In JavaScript, Any symbol that is declared acts as a reference variable until that variable stores primitives? for example foo is a reference variable pointing to a function object(foo) at some address? Is this function object an instance of any class? where as bar is not a reference variable(but data variable) holding some value? is that correct?

Comment: Python names are only bound when actually assigned to. So the names don't actual exist until assignment is executed; guard an assignment with a conditional test and you could end up with a name error where JavaScript would return `undefined` instead.

Comment: Felix As part of hoisting, Does Java script interpreter looks for all variables and function declaration and their bindings before execution? what is 'it' in your answer 'it looks for all'? Does it also look for the type of variables as part of hoisting like String/Number?

Comment: @Sham: "It" being the thing that executes the code, the JavaScript interpreter/engine, however you want to call it. E.g. when a function is executed, before any line of it's body is executed, all variable and function declarations are evaluated. Which values the variables get assigned eventually doesn't matter.

Comment: say if my code has 'var bar = function(){return this}; bar()'  here, i see that global object is being passed to bar function. What is this global object? Is global frame in above diagram relate to this global object?

Comment: @Sham: Not sure what frames are in this case. The ECMAScript specification defines a global object with certain predefined properties:http://es5.github.io/#x15.1. Additionally, all global variables are actually properties of the global object. In browsers, `window` is the global object.

Comment: oh ok. So bar will become the member of global object window. And if i say, 'foo = {}' and create an object, will this object also becomes a member of window object or a child of window object(with proto inheritance relation)?

Comment: @Sham: No object inherits from `window`. The scope (chain) and inheritance/prototype (chain) are two totally different things.

Comment: you mean when i say 'foo = {}', foo will become the member of window object as a property member?